# Finding start and end position of a word in a string in java

Tags: java, regex, string, substring

What is the best way for for finding start and end  position of a "substring" in a sentence?

for example for sentence `"This is my first program"`, by giving the substring `"my first"` It should return `start position=2` and `end position=4`.

Comment: Visit the [`String API`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/String.html) and enjoy life. If you won't be satisfied you'll get your money back.

Comment: Have you found _a_ way?

Comment: Also, are the positions based on the number of words or the number of characters?

Comment: @Sotirios Delimanolis: actually, I couldnt find any effective way! they are based on number words.

Comment: can you explain what startposition and endposition are and how you want them to work?

Comment: Show us your ineffective way and tell us why it was ineffective.

Answer (score 10):

In just two steps, you can get the starting position and the ending position of a word in the sentence.

```
public String startEndPosition(String sentence, String word) {
    int startingPosition = sentence.indexOf(word);
    int endingPosition = startingPosition + word.length();
    return "start position=" + startingPosition + " end position=" + endingPosition;
}
```

- The method `indexOf` will get you the starting position of the word in the sentence.
- Adding the length of the word with the starting position will give you the end position of the word in the sentence.

Answer (score 2):

The following code does the trick. The algorithm works by finding the index of the first occurence of your substring.

The start index of your substring is then equal to the number of words that occured before your substring. We can find this amount by splitting the string before your first match in words and counting the number of words. The end index is the start index augmented by the number of words in your substring.

```
public static Range find(String string, String substring) {
    int index = string.indexOf(substring);
    if (index < 0)
        throw new IllegalStateException();
    int start = string.substring(0,index).split(" +").length;
    int end = start + substring.split(" +").length;
    return new Range(start, end);
}

public class Range {
    public final int start;
    public final int end;

    public Range(int start, int end) { this.start = start; this.end = end; };

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return String.format("start position=%d end position=%d", start, end);
    }
}
```

Example code :

```
System.out.println(find("This is my first program", "my first"));
```

Output:

```
start position=2 end position=4
```

Answer (score 0):

This should work fine:

```
public static void main(String args[])
{
    String[] sentence = "This is my first program".split(" ");
    String[] words = "my first".split(" ");

    int start = -1;

    for (int i = 0, j = 0; i < sentence.length && j < words.length; i++) {
        if (sentence[i].equals(words[j])) {
            if (j++ == 0)
                start = i;
        } else {
            start = -1;
            j = 0;
        }
    }

    if (start == -1)
        System.out.println("doesnt' match");
    else
        System.out.println(start + " - " + (start + words.length));
}
```