# how to get index by keyword in a string?

Tags: java, string

if I have a String:

```
String str = "Hello, World!";
```

how can I get index of a key word:

```
int begin_index = str.GetKeywordIndex("World").GetBeginIndex();
int end_index = str.GetkeyWordIndex("World").GetEndIndex();

System.out.println("keyword World begin at:" + begin_index + "end: " + end_index);

// keyword World begin at: 7, end: 11
```

ps: I don't want to use for loop iterate String, because it's too slow

Comment: startIndex=[indexOf()](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#indexOf(java.lang.String)). endIndex=startIndex+word.[length()](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#length())

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Finding start and end position of a word in a string in java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27926026/finding-start-and-end-position-of-a-word-in-a-string-in-java)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

int begin_index = str.undexOf("World");

int end_index = begin_index+"World".length();

System.out.println("keyword World begin at:" + begin_index + "end: " + end_index);